# Sample size calculation for cluster randomized trials

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-power

The study is cluster randomized trial and the incidence rates is the outcome, for follow-up over a 3 year period.
We expected malaria episode mean of 1 episode per person-year in control tools in the Non-Intervention community (NIC) and assuming a reduction to at least 0.50 (by 50%) the mean malaria episodes per person-year in the intervention community (IC) and based on a power of about 80%.
How to calculate the sample size (number of clusters per group)?

Comment: Sample size also depends on statistical methods used after data collection. So what method will you use after trial?

Comment: We plan to use Regression model to estimate the incidence rate ratio